# Expression not in GROUP BY key

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hi I tried to run this query:

```
select
count(id) as Total_books_in_store,
sum(case when type in ('sports', 'music', 'history') then 1 else 0 end) AS Total_sold,
(Total_sold/Total_books_in_store) as Sales_rate
from store
group by total_in_store
```

when I ran this query, it gave me error:

**Line 5:1 Expression not in GROUP BY key**

I have the table id and type but I tried to calculate the ratio without success.

Comment: "Sales rate" is grouping three different book types as one. Are you sure that's what you want to do? Also, not clear what you're grouping by, but it shouldn't be the total or the count, which are already aggregates

Comment: Although it is clear that you are not using `group by` correctly, it would be good for us to know what exactly you are trying to achieve to provide you a proper solution. So, please edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48881716/edit your question and provide some sample data and expected output. What does `total_in_store` column contain or is it an alias you created? Please explain.

Comment: try to explain what result you want from your query. it is not properly written and the output expected is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH Calculation AS(
    SELECT
        count(id) as Total_books_in_store,
        sum(case when type in ('sports', 'music', 'history') then 1 else 0 end) AS Total_sold
    from @Store
    group by total_in_store
)

SELECT
    Total_books_in_store,
    Total_sold,
    (Total_sold/Total_books_in_store) as Sales_rate
FROM Calculation
```